# .Net Why GC does not remove objects from heap?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I've written simple test program:

```
namespace GCTest {
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var a1 = new A();
        a1.AProperty = new A();
        a1.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a1.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a1.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        Console.WriteLine("a1 created");
        Console.ReadKey();

        var a2 = new A();
        a2.AProperty = new A();
        a2.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a2.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a2.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        Console.WriteLine("a2 created");
        Console.ReadKey();

        var a3 = new A();
        a3.AProperty = new A();
        a3.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a3.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a3.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        Console.WriteLine("a3 created");
        Console.ReadKey();

        var a4 = new A();
        a4.AProperty = new A();
        a4.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a4.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a4.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        Console.WriteLine("a4 created");
        Console.ReadKey();

        var a5 = new A();
        a5.AProperty = new A();
        a5.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a5.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();
        a5.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty.AProperty = new A();

        Console.WriteLine("a5 created");
        int a1Gen = GC.GetGeneration(a1);
        Console.WriteLine("a1 generation: " + a1Gen);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        a1Gen = GC.GetGeneration(a1);
        Console.WriteLine("a1 generation: " + a1Gen);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        a1Gen = GC.GetGeneration(a1);
        Console.WriteLine("a1 generation: " + a1Gen);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        a1Gen = GC.GetGeneration(a1);
        Console.WriteLine("a1 generation: " + a1Gen);
        Console.ReadKey();

        a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = a5 = null;
        Console.WriteLine("a1-a5 are null");
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine("GC");
        GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine("GC");
        GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine("GC");
        GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.ReadKey();

        Console.WriteLine("GC");
        GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class A {
    int[] arr = new int[1000];
    public A() {
        arr[0] = 1;
    }

    public A AProperty { get; set; }
}
```

}

I make snapshots using build-in Visual Studio 2017 diagnostic tools.
When a1 - a5 variables are initialized, there are 25 A instances in the heap, as expected:

[image]

But after variables a1-a5 become equal to null, even after additional calls of GC.Collect method, the heap still contains A instances. And more calls of GC.Collect doesn't reduce A objects in the heap. Why? Is there way to force collect ALL unused objects?

[image]

EDIT:
I've switched to the Release configuration and I see that in the heap there are 15 objects after initializing a1-a5 variables:

[image]

And after GC.Collect calls still remains 14 objects.

Comment: Debug or release build?

Comment: Debug, .Net 4.5

Comment: In a debug build, or if you hook up the debugger, the life of variables, even temporary variables generated by the compiler, has their life extended to the end of methods to facilitate breakpoints and inspecting variables that a method no longer uses. Switch to release build and try it again.

Comment: I've switched to the Release configuration. Now after initializing a1-a5 variables VS shows' that in the heap there are 15 objects, and after assignment null still remains 14 A instances.

Comment: Then it might be that the tool you're using to find these objects is acting like a debugger. There is metadata in the assembly (if I remember correctly) that identifies the spans of method code where a variable is considered "in use", this span stops after last write or read. If the code is executing *after* such a span, the variable is considered dead and whether it has a reference or not should be ignored, but these spans are extended when a debugger is present, so perhaps that tool is acting like one and this messes this us.

Comment: A different approach, can you try moving all the code that allocates these objects into a separate method and call this from the method you have in your question? This would negate the effect of these things since the variables are no longer on the call stack once you get to the GC bit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how VS handles this, but if I run your code using a release build I don't see any instances of `A` on the heap when inspecting it using SOS.

To see for yourself, [download WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools). Then attach to your process and load SOS.

```
.loadby sos clr
```

You can dump the entire heap using `!dumpheap -stat` or just the type using `!dumpheap -type GCTest.A`.

You should see instances going up as they are created. Once GC has reclaimed the instances you shouldn't see any instances of `A` on the heap.

Here's the output following the first GC after all references are nulled.

```
0:001> !dumpheap -type GCTest.A
 Address       MT     Size

Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
Total 0 objects
```

Comment: This is expected behavior indeed. Most probably using Diagnostic tools in VS switches JIT to debug mode.

Comment: @KonradKokosa that could be. My point was just that this is probably a tooling issue. PS: Nice to meet you and I'm looking forward to reading your book :)

Comment: nice to meet you too! Indeed, it only shows how careful one should be when doing so simple-scenario investigations...